# Can you call a function on recv?

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I am trying to make a messaging application using tkinter as a GUI. I want to call a function when a recv a message, this function will actually display a message, but using a while loop it can sometimes crash or mess up updates on my GUI.

I tried calling a subprogram after I connected to the server...

```py
def get_msg(): # This will run code that will get messages
    while True:
        Crecv = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode() # Waits for a message
        print(Crecv) # Prints whatever the server has sent into console
        messages.insert(END, Crecv) # Insets the message into the message Listbox
```

This didn't work, I assumed it was because of the while loop (as I would just crash after connecting)

Now I want to try calling the subprogram when receiving the message only.

Here is my server.py script

```py
from socket import *
import socket
import select

## -- Server (Rooms) -- ##
users = []
addresses = []

host_name = socket.gethostname()

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(host_name) 
PORT = 12345

print(f"Server Info\nHOST: {HOST}\nPORT: {PORT}")


serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
serversocket.listen(5)
clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()

def user_join():
    # Append username to users[]
    # Append user address to adresses[]
    print(f"{address} connecting (nicked {username})")
    clientsocket.send(f"{username} joined the room!").encode()

print(address)
with clientsocket:
    while True:
        Srecv = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
        print(f"{address}: {Srecv}")
        # Add server time to message before sending
        clientsocket.sendall(Srecv.encode())
```

This is something I will update later, which is why there are some unused lists etc.

The idea is.... Client connects to server -> Client sends a message -> server.py will decode the message and then send it to everyone who is connected -> OP Client will re-receive the message and make it display, other Clients will just receive the message and display it.

This is what I am trying to achieve at the end of the project, but I can't even connect to the server as my client crashes as soon as I connect.

I copied all my socket code from a non-GUI version of my project called client.py

```py
from socket import *
import socket

## -- Server (Room) -- ##
host = input("Host: ")
port = int(input("Port: "))

username = input("Username: ")
username = "<" + username + ">"
print(f"Connecting under nick \"{username}\"")

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Creates socket
clientsocket.connect((host, port)) # Connects to the server

while True:
    Csend = input("MSG: ") # Input message
    #Csend = f"{username} {Csend}" # Add username to message
    clientsocket.send(Csend.encode()) # Send message to ONLY the server

    print(clientsocket.recv(1024).decode())
```

Comment: Did you enter the server IP correctly?

Comment: Your server can only handle one client connection.  You should use threads to support multiple client connections.

Comment: @acw1668 
I copied the IP from the server.py console. I copied the port correctly. I can get a connection working, it just crashes after making that connection.

Also I will look into socket threads, thanks.

Comment: Post the error messages.

Comment: @acw1668 There are none. It just crashes the GUI and ends the application.

Comment: Your code should work.  Did you run the server and client in terminal/console?  Since your posted code has no GUI code, the crash may not related to posted code, but in your GUI part.

Comment: @acw1668 I think I have found the issue, I have a function called get_msg() and when it is finished executing the code it recalls the function. But it is crashing before it even completes the first line of code, which is Crecv = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode(), the other lines are just printing the message and displaying it in a Listbox